# Fix xticks with decimals for pandas histplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, axis-labels

I'm using pandas to create this plot:

```
df.Rank.hist(by=df['code'],figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

Where variable `code` refers to the title of each plot.
This is the only code that found that worked at getting different plots per group... if there's any other simpler way, please bring it up.

What is a way to fix the x-axis ticks with decimals? It's very strange because there are no rows with those numbers (2.5,7.5,etc) in the dataframe, only integers. Should look like plot 2 (LP_DEBTC) but numbers being shown 1 by 1 instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Change the `bins`? Btw, note that a histogram is not a bar chart. If you want a bar chart, use `.plot.bar`.

Comment: @BigBen changing the bins didn't do it... don't think I can do the plots-by-group with `.plot.bar` (at least, it is taking more than 5 minutes to run)

Comment: I want a histogram as I need to count/percentage of each "rank" for each "code". So for example, in plot 1 I can see we ranked #1 15000 times when the code was "lp_car", that's what I want to know.